# How to show that if $A$ has eigenvalues $\{\lambda_i\},$ then $-A$ has eigenvalues $\{-\lambda_i\}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

How can I show that if $A$ is (real) square matrix that has eigenvalues $\{\lambda_i\},$ then $-A$ has eigenvalues $\{-\lambda_i\},$ i.e., the same set, but negated?

I think it should be obvious, but it is eluding me for the moment.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** If $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$, it is also an eigenvector of $-A$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: if $A v = \lambda v$, what is $-Av$?

Answer (score 0):

$Av=\lambda v$ for some nonzero $v$. Then $(-A)v=- \lambda v$.